# Сквозная функциональность. Как лучше реализовать?

Tags: c, проектирование, логирование, обработка-ошибок

Появилась проблем при проектировании приложения связанная с ведением лога и обработки ошибок. Допустим, есть такой код:

```
void set_opengl_attr(const bool _set_double_buff, const int _msaa_level) {
    // Проверить значение _msaa_level, которое должно быть равно 0, 2, 4, 8 или 16.
    // Если значение другое, обработать ошибку и записать в лог.

    // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
    // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, _msaa_level);

    if (_set_double_buff == true) {
        // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
        SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    }

    // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
    // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
    // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
    // Проверить вернула ли функция значение 0 (успешно), если нет - записать ошибку в лог.
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
}
```

Если реализовать все проверки, то выйдет вот это:

```
void set_opengl_attr(const bool _set_double_buff, const int _msaa_level) {
    if (_msaa_level != 0) {
        if (_msaa_level != 2 && _msaa_level != 4 && 
            _msaa_level != 8 && _msaa_level != 16) {
            print_to_log("Error: Uncorrect _msaa_level. Set _msaa_level as 0");
        } else {
            SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLEBUFFERS, 1);
            SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_MULTISAMPLESAMPLES, _msaa_level);
        }
    }

    if (_set_double_buff == true) {
        if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1) != 0) {
            print_to_log("Error: SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1) failed.");
        }
    }

    if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8) != 0) {
        print_to_log("Error: SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1) failed.");
    }

    if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8) != 0) {
        print_to_log("Error: SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8) failed.");
    }

    if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8) != 0) {
        print_to_log("Error: SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8) failed.");
    }

    if (SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8) != 0) {
        print_to_log("Error: SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8) failed.");
    }
}
```

В **три** раза больше кода! Конечно, я переборщил со всеми проверками, но это лишь пример, чтобы Вы поняли о чем я. Может, у кого-то была таже проблема? Расскажите, как Вы ее решили. Интересуют только возможности языка Си. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: таки макросы можно, которые в те же ифы развернутся

Comment: Можно сделать функции-обертки

Comment: Grundy, так проверки все-равно останутся. Или я что-то не так понял? Может, напишите код?

Comment: @Eanmos, чтобы уведомление пришло перед ником надо ставить `@` иначе пользователь просто не увидит, что ему ответили

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Один из вариантов - обернуть функции `SDL` в свои, которые будут включать проверку/вывод лога, например так:

```
int SDL_GL_SetAttribute_Check(SDL_GLattr attr, int value, const char* hint) {
    int ret = SDL_GL_SetAttribute(attr, value);
    if (ret) {
        print_to_log("SDL_GL_SetAttribute failed");
        print_to_log(hint);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Вызываем (третий аргумент - строка, которая может дать подсказку о месте ошибки):

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute_Check(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8, "SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8");
```

---

Альтернативный вариант - использование макросов:

```
#define LOG_IF(EXP) do { if (EXP) print_to_log("Error: " #EXP " failed."); } while (0)
```

Используем:

```
LOG_IF(SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8));
```

Здесь в случае ошибки будет выведена строка вызова функции, использованная в аргументе макроса:

```
Error: SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8) failed.
```

Вариант с макросом более универсальный, т.к. может принимать любую функцию.

Comment: Можно еще добавить в макрос макропеременные `__FILE__, __LINE__, __FUNCTION__` , чтобы точнее локализовать ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Ну, здесь есть два варианта:

1. После сдачи программы в эксплуатацию Вы скрываетесь и никогда не
   будете подключены к процессу "сопровождения" Вашей программы. Тога
   "if (RetCode != 0)" писать совсем не обязательно. :-)
2. Вам придётся сопровождать Вашу программу. Тогда, в целях сохранения собственного психического здоровья, настоятельно рекомендую все эти "if" писать после КАЖДОЙ функции, которая возвращает код ошибки.

Только два совета:

- Вместо "print_to_log" используйте СТАНДАРТНЫЙ "syslog". Никогда, ни при каких обстоятельствах, сообщения об ошибки не должны выдаваться на консоль!
- После выдачи сообщения об ошибке, обязательно ставьте "exit(-1);"

Comment: "После выдачи сообщения об ошибке, обязательно ставьте "exit(-1);", а если после ошибки не нужно закрывать приложение? Ведь, не все ошибки фатальны.

Comment: "Вместо "print_to_log" используйте СТАНДАРТНЫЙ "syslog". Никогда, ни при каких обстоятельствах, сообщения об ошибки не должны выдаваться на консоль!", а кто Вам сказал, что print_to_log вообще выводит собщение на консоль? Этой функции в моем проекте вообще нет. Я написал ее для примера. Простите, если ввел в заблуждение)

Comment: **не все ошибки фатальны** - Не фатальными могут быть только ошибки В/В. Есть шанс, что при повторении операции в/в она завершится нормально. Поверьте, любые другие ошибки - фатальны!  Фатальны в том смысле, что когда автор программы пытается исправить ситуацию, он вступает в область ПРЕДПОЛОЖЕНИЙ. А это приводит к любым, совершенно непредсказуемым  последствиям. Человек предполагает, а Бог - располагает. Помните ? :-)

Comment: **rто Вам сказал, что print_to_log вообще выводит собщение на консоль?**  Её название. Большинство программ, которые пишут программисты - это демоны (в виндосе - сервисы), которые вообще не имеют связи с консолью. И попытка ввода.вывода на консоль из таких программ приводит, зачастую, к очень странным результатам :-)

Comment: если бы после всех ошибок вызвали `exit`, у нас бы с Вами не загрузилась ни одна ОС. Очень редки случаи, когда ОС грузиться без единой ошибки. Посмотрите в интернете, сколько у людей нефатальных ошибок, тот же __ACPII Probe failed__ :-).

Comment: **Большинство программ, которые пишут программисты - это демоны...**, ну здесь я, конечно, не соглашусь, у меня на linux'е наберет от силы 20 демонов. Большая часть программ - прикладная.

Comment: **Большая часть программ - прикладная.** - скорее всего - на GUI. И кто будет смотреть (а главное - как?) на консольный вывод из-под GUI?

Comment: **Очень редки случаи, когда ОС грузиться без единой ошибки** - так я и говорю - ошибки В/В!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44422/discussion-between-eanmos-and-sergey).